# Sending string from servlet to ajax function

Tags: ajax, servlets

I am making an ajax request to my servlet and the servelt responds with this code:

```
resp.getOutputStream().print("t")
```

In the ajax onreadystate function I am doing

```
if(xmlhttp.responseText.equals("t")){//...}
```

But it is not entering into the if statement. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String objects don't have any "equals" method in Javascript. You should use the '==' operator instead.